# Rearranging keyboard layout options in menu

Tags: menu-bar, input-source

I have a few keyboard layouts available in the input sources menu. They currently look like this:

[image]

I'd like to have ABC extended at the top, and make a few other rearrangements. Is that possible?

Comment: Wish you luck. I thought it might be the order added, but it's not. It appears to have some self-determiner as to which order they appear. If I add & remove any, they go back to the same place in the list. Not alphabetical, but mine seems to put the 'englishes' at the top, British or US. Example of menu reflecting control panel but *not* the prefs file - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UagK.png